# In the output of SysInternals Handle.exe what does RWD stand for?

Tags: windows, sysinternals, handle

I'm using `handle.exe` from SysInternals to grab information about open handles. Running just `handle.exe -p cmd` to get the handles for `cmd.exe`, I get the following output. Other output is similar, just much longer.

```
cmd.exe pid: 22916 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
   3C: File  (RW-)   C:\Windows
   7C: File  (RW-)   C:\Program Files (x86)\ManageEngine\AssetExplorer\bin
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cmd.exe pid: 22264 RADHSV\nsshinabarger
   3C: File  (RW-)   C:\Users\nsshinabarger\Downloads\Handle
  12C: File  (R-D)   C:\Windows\System32\en-US\cmd.exe.mui
```

I assume the `R` and `W` stand for read and write, but I can't seem to find documentation on what the `D` stands for. Could someone tell me what it stands for, or point me towards documentation?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have process explorer?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yes, although that's not what I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: This answer explains with some in-depth of Windows kernel stuff.

#### Gist:

`SharedAccess` parameter from [`NtCreateFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile).

```
| Name | ShareAccess       |  Value   |
|:----:|:-----------------:|:--------:|
| R    | FILE_SHARE_READ   | 1        |
| W    | FILE_SHARE_WRITE  | 2        |
| D    | FILE_SHARE_DELETE | 4        |
```

#### How it works

- The handle program gets the process ID from the process name. Then it passes
  the process ID/client ID to the Process Explorer's kernel mode driver aka. `PROCEXP152.sys` file.
  If the driver is not present it creates one.
- In kernel mode, `0x8335004C` IOCTL query iterates all the associated objects/handles
  with that process and determines the object type with [`ZwQueryObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567062(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle).
- When a 'file' handle is received, with `0x83350048` IOCTL query,
  [`ZwOpenProcess()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-ntopenprocess) and [`ObReferenceObjectByHandle()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obreferenceobjectbyhandle) creates a [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.
- Then the kernel mode driver creates a bit-field by checking the shared access booleans, like this:

```c
if (FileObject->SharedRead)
    Mode |= 1;
if (FileObject->SharedWrite)
    Mode |= 2;
if (FileObject->SharedDelete)
    Mode |= 4;
```

And the user mode program receives that 'Mode' and converts them into characters, like this:

```c
FirstBit = '-';
SecondBit = '-';
if (Mode & 4)
    FirstBit = 'D';
ThirdBit = '-';
if (Mode & 2)
    ThirdBit = 'W';
if (Mode & 1)
    SecondBit = 'R';
```

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful! So basically `RWD` indicates if it's sharing read, write, or delete permissions with other processes?

Comment: @theTheodidact Read the NtCreateFile docs as I said. That's it. If you want to know more open the handle program and the driver in Ghidra.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [sharing mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/creating-and-opening-files) of the file handle – see dwShareMode under CreateFile() in the Win32 API documentation.

Sharing mode is practically the opposite of "mandatory locks", the program specifies when opening a file whether other programs should be allowed to simultaneously open it. (I believe it dates back to MS-DOS era "LAN Manager" networking. See also [SMB protocol documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/managing-file-locks).)

The letters stand for **r**ead/**w**rite/**d**elete.